# running shell_exec in php causes web server to hang

Tags: php, drupal-6, shell-exec

I am running the following code. What it does is take a text file, splits it into parts that end with '_part'  ending and than calls the same script with a flag to process the files - uploading the content to a Drupal system.

What happens is that the script runs and finishes the work, all invoked scripts finish too and I can see the results. but each time after I run it the web server stops responding. Is there anything basic that I am missing or doing wrong?

```
  if(isset($argv[3])){
    $isSplit = $argv[3] == 'true' ? true : false;
  }      
  if($isSplit){                  
    $fileSplitter = new CSVFileParts($fileName);
    $parts = $fileSplitter->split_file();
    echo 'Splited file to '.$parts.' parts'.PHP_EOL;
    for($part =0; $part < $parts; $part++){            
      echo shell_exec('php Service.php u ./partial_files/'.basename($fileName).'.part_'.$part.' false > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
    }        
  }else{                            
    $log->lwrite('uploading '.$argv[2]); 
    $drupalUploader = new DrupalUploader($fileName, $log);
    $drupalUploader->upload();        
  }
```

Comment: Could you try echo shell_exec('php Service.php u ./partial_files/'.basename($fileName).'.part_'.$part.' > /dev/null; echo $?');

Comment: I'm also curious if the $parts var is a count of how many parts you have or a array. Because in your array you do like so $part < $parts, maybe try sizeof($parts)

Comment: Are you sure the script finishes? You wrote, you can see the result, but how do your really track that the script has finished?

Comment: @wesso - $parts is the number of parts file splitter has made. it a number not an array.

Comment: @hakre - i see the results on the Drupal system, items were uploaded as expected. running "ps -aux | grep php"  on the server shows the invoked processes and after a while shows only the "ps" command so an educated guess is that the processes finish.

Comment: if ps doesn't list PHP any longer, it's finished, yes. You can see which process hangs with ps?

Comment: Its not the process that hangs, its the whole server stops responding to anything else than pings, no ssh, no http or ftp. I must say that each process bootstrap's the full Drupal API inside the DrupalUploader and inserts new nodes through node_save method.

Comment: Nothing in the apache error log or the php error log?

Comment: nothing in the apache log. Checking the PHP log...no logging for php. my bad. I'll set one up to see if anything comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string`

shell_exec expects the file handle to be open, but you redirect everything to /dev/null and detach it.

As you plan to detach the process and remove all the output, you should use exec() and escapeshellcmd()

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php